# "font-family: fantasy" looks weird in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

Google-chrome renders the font family(type) fantasy in bold.
see http://jsfiddle.net/Q7mQD/
image http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/26/capturexgd.jpg/
How to fix this?

Comment: for that I have to accept incorrect answers?

Comment: Nope, not at all. Looks like you've accepted a lot, so I take it back, and please ignore my meddling. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propably a Chrome bug, since Chrome also does this for other fonts.

E.g. when I open Zimbra (mail) I have the same issue.

Same goes for some other sites.

Answer (score 1):

`fantasy` is a generic family name. The browser can use whatever font it wants.

Try using `font-weight: normal` or using a custom font. [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) has some nice fonts you could use.

Comment: using font-weight normal havnt made big difference